# A story about a computer virus and blinking network card lights

Tags: story-identification

So, I'm trying to find this story about some two engineers in a lab or server room which are detecting some unusual network anomalies but can't pinpoint them. Eventually they see that an old network card which has blinking LED-s is indicating some traffic is happening, and they manage to find a virus in the network. But it is completely benign, not doing any outages or harm, just running in the background and slowly spreading. Whatever they try, they can't remove it, almost like it's learning how to bypass their countermeasures. The story ends with the hard truth that they just let it be, and hope it doesn't evolve into something evil.

Does someone remember it? Or know where to find it? I've seen it on some old-looking site, having just text, much like RFC specifications (e.g. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a short story then?  Approximately when did you read it?

Comment: [This was asked and answered just last month](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241656/looking-for-a-short-story-about-a-network-problem-being-caused-by-an-ai-in-the-f). It's [Coding Machines](https://www.teamten.com/lawrence/writings/coding-machines/) by Lawrence Kesteloot. Mateo, if this is the story can you let us know and we'll link this question to the previous one.

Comment: that's it! thank you for putting the pieces together :) you can link the questions